# Can't install Spotify for Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: installation, command-line, apt, package-management

As the title says, I can't install spotify. I've googled for answers but nothing was relevant to the case. Another problem is that I can't install wine (so I have to install Spotify through Terminal).

I've followed the instructions at spotifys web.

But when I run `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
```

I got this:

```
chucknorris@ubuntu:~$ /etc/apt/sources.list
bash: /etc/apt/sources.list: Permission denied
chucknorris@ubuntu:~$ deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
No command 'deb' found, did you mean:
 Command 'debc' from package 'devscripts' (main)
 Command 'derb' from package 'libicu-dev' (main)
 Command 'dab' from package 'bsdgames' (universe)
 Command 'debi' from package 'devscripts' (main)
 Command 'xdeb' from package 'xdeb' (universe)
 Command 'dwb' from package 'dwb' (universe)
deb: command not found
chucknorris@ubuntu:~$
```

So what should I do? 
PS. I have reinstalled Ubuntu a couple of times because of problems and the first Ubuntu (also 12.10) I was able to install it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need root privileges to modify the `/etc/sources.list`

Try this:

```
sudo chmod o+w /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo echo "deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 94558F59
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y spotify-client
```

Comment: Thanx, that helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

thats not the way how to add a source.

open your terminal and then follow the steps one by one.

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

then it will open a text file and in that file place the following line at the last

```
deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
```

then save & close the file.

now do as

```
sudo apt-get update       
sudo apt-get install spotify
```

Comment: You've to add key first, before install.

Comment: @OrangeTux Ok thanks.so you want me to place key in my answer too or deleting my answer ?

Comment: So the correct way to add a repository is via sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list? I think I tried it but it didn't work. I will try it next time, thx :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that they easy way to install spotify in ubuntu is to next method:

Open a terminal and paste

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free"
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 94558F59
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install spotify-client
```

at least I did it that way, and still working